# Fourier transform of $\sin(2\pi fm t) \sin(2\pi fc t) $

Tags: fourier-analysis

How do I find the Fourier transform of $\sin(2\pi f_m t)\sin(2\pi f_c t) $?

My main confusion comes from $fm$ and $fc$. If I had the same frequency I could of used a trig identity and then Fourier transform it but with different frequencies I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $f_m$ and $f_c$? (I'm assuming you meant to put subscripts.)

Comment: Instead I think $f$ is a frequency and $m$ and $c$ are integer numbers.

Comment: You can use $\sin(a)\sin(b) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(a-b) - \cos(a+b))$

Comment: $\mathscr F \{ cos(at) \}=\frac{1}{2} (\delta (f-a)+\delta (f+a))$

Comment: Start with $
\sin(2\pi f_m t)\sin(2\pi f_c t) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos(2\pi(f_m-f_c)t)+\cos(2\pi(f_m+f_c)t)\right]
$